# setUbiquitous: error code = 513

Tags: ios, ios5, icloud, nsfilemanager

I am trying to save file from bundle to iCloud by using `setUbiquitous` API of `NSFileManager`, But its returning `error code= 513`,

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x1e099830 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted".
```

Please anyone help me to solve this.

```
- (IBAction)addFileToiCloud:(id)sender {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"rtf"];
    NSURL *localURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localPath];

    NSLog(@"Local file path = %@",localURL);


    // Create the new URL object on a background queue.
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *filename = @"test.rtf";

    NSURL * newDocumentURL = [[[fm
                         URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
                  isDirectory:YES] URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    NSLog(@"***** iCloud = %@",newDocumentURL);

    NSError *error;

    BOOL saved = [fm setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:localURL destinationURL:newDocumentURL error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);

    NSLog(@"New Document URL = %d",saved);
});

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

edit your code like below:

```
NSURL * newDocumentURL = [[fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename] ;

BOOL saved = [fm setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] destinationURL:newDocumentURL error:&error];
```